# save git log date format in .gitconfig

Tags: git

I can specify custom date format for `git log`

```
git log --reverse --date=format:'%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

but when I try to save this in `.gitconfig`, it has no effect

```
[format]
  date = format:'%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

How can I customize my date format in `.gitconfig` ?
also, how can I save `--reverse` in `.gitconfig` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying `date=format` for `log` command and not `format` as below

```
[log]
  date = format:'%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

For specifying `--reverse` you can use `alias` like below:

```
[log]
    date=format:'%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S' 
[alias]
    lg = log --reverse
```

After these changes your `git log` will print with the specified format and when you write `git lg` will be printed `git log` with `--reverse`.

Comment: is it possible to save `--reverse` as a global option? I don't want to use an alias with a different name, ie `git lg` instead of `git log`.

Comment: @MartinVegter no you can't, there is no such variable for `log` see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-logabbrevCommit.